# Can you share data across provisioning profiles using the keychain?

Tags: ios, keychain

I want to share application data between two developer profiles is this possible to do with the keychain access?

From reading the documentation it sounds like you are restricted to the identifier preceding the application id. EX: GUS8339.com.company.app would restrict you to GUS8339 profile signed applications

Answer (score 3):

You're correct, but it's slightly more complicated:

- **The provisioning profiles must have the same bundle seed.** This is set when you create the corresponding "app ID". An app can change app ID after you've submitted it to the App Store, but note non-wildcard app IDs must have unique bundle IDs (that is, if you've already set up a non-wildcard app ID for the app, you can only change it to use a wildcard app ID).
- **You have to give both apps access to the same "keychain access group".** This is set in the app entitlements. I think Xcode has a working UI for editing these now. You can use a wildcard access group, but I don't think this is recommended.

The relevant portion of the provisioning profile looks something like this (open one in your favourite text editor):

```
<key>Entitlements</key>
<dict>
  <key>application-identifier</key>
  <string>A1B2C3D4E5.com.example.myapp</string>
  <key>aps-environment</key>
  <string>production</string>
  <key>get-task-allow</key>
  </false>
  <key>keychain-access-groups</key>
  <array>
    <string>A1B2C3D4E5.*</string>
  </array>
</dict>
```

This restricts what you can put in the entitlements, but you should be able to specify something like

```
  <key>keychain-access-groups</key>
  <array>
    <string>A1B2C3D4E5.com.example.myappsuite</string>
  </array>
```

Note that you may need to specify this to the keychain API!

Comment: Note in the original question: "GUS8339.com.company.app would restrict you to GUS8339 profile signed applications".

Answer (score -2):

Keychain access groups depend on the bundle seed ID - the value "GUS8339" that is unique to your provisioning profile. So to answer more directly, no, you can't use access groups across different provisioning profiles, as the seed ID is basically the provisioning profile ID in your example.

Comment: It's not unique to the profile. It's set as part of the "app ID", but app IDs can share the same bundle seed, and I believe for new companies it defaults to the team ID.

Comment: App IDs can share the same bundle seed if they are on the same provisioning profile, as the bundle seed id is part of what makes the providing profile and entitlements unique. The question is wether applications with different provisioning profiles *AND* different seed IDs can use access groups to read each other's keychains. They can't.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Security/Reference/keychainservices/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/SecItemAdd

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2250/_index.html

Comment: But what if you knew this data:

<key>keychain-access-groups</key>
  <array>
    <string>A1B2C3D4E5.*</string>
  </array>

Could you then, knowing the other application's keychain access string, get data out of their keychain? Or is the permission strictly not granted. I'm guessing jailbroken devices would allow this kind of data sharing without hassling applications of not having permissions to that area.